# Subclassing based on iOS platform version

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking, I have a subclass created for AFHTTPSessionManager which works on iOS7, i would like to know it is possible that i can inherit the same subclass but with a different super class say AFHTTPRequestOperationManager based on some preprocessor directives.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "standard" way to deal with this would be to define an interface for your class functions, then create "old" and "new" classes to implement the interface.  Use a "factory" to create the correct one for the runtime environment.

You could instead use a "wrapper" class instead of the interface -- one that creates the version-specific class internally and forwards calls to it.

Comment: So you're saying a class cluster?

Comment: Uh, yeah, I suppose.  (I just realized you were talking Objective-C -- I for some reason was thinking this was for Java.  But the same ideas apply -- just use "protocol" instead of "interface".)

Comment: +1 for the use of a factory here. The Objective-c way to do this would be to use a class cluster that when you init, it determines the os version and returns the correct instance depending on iOS7 / 6. Message Forwarding is not needed in this case because the class each class in the cluster will respond correctly to the methods defined in the header.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the use of a Factory (in the form of a class cluster)

**note that code below is only an indication, it won't compile from a copy/paste**

```
@interface MyHTTPClient

- (void) post:(NSURLRequest *)request params:(NSDictionary *)params
@end


@implementation MyHTTPClient

- (id) init {
    if(iOS_version < 7) {
        return [[_MyiOS7HttpClient] alloc] init];
    } else {
        return [[_MyiOS6HttpClient alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void) post:(NSURLRequest *)request params:(NSDictionary *)params {
    NSAssert(NO, @"private instances should respond to this");
}
@end
```

now the private instances, which are not visible from the project (only via `MyHttpClient`)

```
#import "MyHttpClient.h"

@implementation _MyiOS7HttpClient

- (void) post:(NSURLRequest *)request params:(NSDictionary *)params {
    // use new ios7 session manager here to do stuff
}
@end
```

and create a similar class for `MyiOS6HttpClient` which uses none of the iOS7 Session management.

So the Class Cluster in this case gives you:

- A Clean interface to either `MyiOS7HttpClient` or `MyIos6HttpClient` via `MyHttpClient`,
- Other code does not need to know which instance you are actually using.
- No Need for message forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this at compile-time. The compiler has no idea which of the supported iOS version(s) your app will run on. You may create several versions of the class, and create the correct one based on a runtime version check.